# Email Notifications for System Performance Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, alerts

I am trying to figure out how to apply email notifications to system performance triggers for example high CPU, High RAM usage, low disk space etc.

I have tried googling it but I am unable to find a guide which walks to through doing this, as I haven't done this before.

Is Windows 2008 R2 capable of doing this or is third party software required?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is split into 2 components:

1) an agent (or agents) which gather the information

2) a processing hub for collating the data and optionally scheduling invocation

There's no end of vendors and products available for this - I use Nagios as it's designed to integrate with all sorts of probes using a very transparent and simple API, there are lots of probes available off the shelf and its available under an open-source licence.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Paessler PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) and it works very well  Very fast to install and it monitors a wide range of host/services, etc It does Netflow and uses SNMP and WMI among other things to monitor.  There is a free eval at www.paessler.com and it is free if the number of things you monitor is low.  Support, when needed has been great as well.  No agents are used in most situations.  Auto discovery works great so you can be up and running an eval very quickly. Runs well in a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Windows Performance Monitor and other onboard tools. There's a [step-by-step instruction from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2424491).

Also, as others have mentioned, there are plenty third party tools for providing such alerts. I have compiled a [list of windows server performance monitoring tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) which should get you started.